# Looping Javascript timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I am trying to run sequential countdown timers but can't figure out how to wait for the timer to finish before moving onto the next item.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var count = 5;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function timer()
{
    count--;
    if (count <= 0)
    {
        $('.workout-timer').text(count + "secs");
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }

    $('.workout-timer').text(count + "secs");
}
```

This just goes into negative, however without the for loop the code counts down from 5 to 0 just fine. So my question is how would get several countdowns one after another? Is the timer not the right way to go about it?

Comment: Don't create 5 intervals. Create one (without a loop).

Comment: why not use `setTimeout`?

Comment: @user2246674 what does this mean?

Comment: @akonsu "why not use setTimeout?" <-- Justify, please. If I'm eating peanut butter, tell me why I should switch to jam.

Comment: the original poster wants to run timers in a succession and cancels them when the handler is called. this is what `setTimeout` is for.

Comment: @akonsu The original code has a flaw because the setInterval is created in a loop and only the last interval is stopped. However, setInterval works perfectly fine, as I show in my answer.

Comment: I think I know what the OP wants. a timer with an associated counter which (a counter) is not global, but in a closure perhaps. so several such timers could be used simultaneously.

Comment: but my last comment did not mention timeouts vs intervals :)

Comment: i want to have several countdowns happen back to back, given the number of objects I will be passing to the loop. so I could have 4 objects that need to countdown one after another from 5-4-3-2-1-0

Comment: @user2246674 `setInterval` with small interval could easily "misbehave" if you have other stuff running which consumes execution time/cpu. In that case the calls will be "remembered" until there is time to execute them - all at "once". Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/402037)

Comment: @user975044 Then create each task after the previous task completes.

Comment: @Andreas Very good link - that *is* justification for using one over the other, depending upon the need.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function startCountdown(count, delay, callback) {
    if (!count) {
        callback && callback();
        return;
    }

    //do something here
    console.log(count);

    setTimeout(function () {
        startCountdown(--count, delay, callback);
    }, delay);
}

startCountdown(5, 1000, function () {
    startCountdown(5, 1500);
});
```

However this can get messy if you have a lot of nested callbacks, but here's one out of many approach you could use to deal with that issue:

```
var queue = [
        { count: 5, delay: 1000 },
        { count: 10, delay: 200 },
        { count: 5, delay: 5000 }
    ];

processNextCountdown();

function processNextCountdown() {
    var options = queue.shift();

    if (options) {
        startCountdown(options.count, options.delay, processNextCountdown);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a timeout over an interval?

Comment: because you do not have to cancel it.

Comment: @akonsu .. so? You only have to create one interval.

Comment: How would i get this to run sequentially? say 10 back to back countdowns?

Comment: I am to achieve multiple countdowns so: 5-4-3-2-1 then again 5-4-3-2-1

Comment: @user975044 I modified the example for your needs.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I did not go this route, I instead used one timer and just set flags for when i needed a count to start and end

Answer (score 1):

[Intervals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) are like timeouts that will reschedule themselves (which [differs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/2246674) from a timeout starting a new timeout). Since intervals reschedule themselves, *only create one*. (Or, only as many as really necessary.)

The problem with the original post is it was creating *5* intervals (because they were being created in the loop) and then only keeping the interval ID (in `counter`) of the last interval created! Thus the `clearInterval` only stopped the last interval and the other 4 intervals kept running and running and running ..

Here is some cleaned up code with comments and without the original problem:

```
var count = 5;
// only need ONE interval
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
// so we do one count RIGHT NOW
timer();

function timer() {
  // display first, so we start at 5: 5, 4 .. 1
  console.log(count);
  count--;
  if (count < 0) {
    // to repeat the count, comment out the clearInterval
    // and do `count = 5;` or similar .. take it from here :D
    clearInterval(counter);
  }
}
```

To create separate "state" for each countdown, either create a new countdown object that maintains state in properties or [use a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). Here is an example with a closure. I have also added support for a callback function to show how such a function can be made more generic:

```
function makeCountdown(startCount, delay, fn) {
    fn = fn || function (i) {
       // default action, if fn not specified
       console.log(i);
    };
    // local variables
    var count = startCount;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, delay);
    timer();

    function timer() {
        // now count and counter refer to variables in the closure (keyword!)
        // which are different each time makeCountdown is called.
        fn(count);
        count--;
        if (count < 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
    }
}

makeCountdown(20, 500); // uses default function
makeCountdown(10, 1000, function (i) { console.log(10 - i) });
makeCountdown(5, 2000, function (i) { console.log("SLOW! " + i) });
```

Exercises:

1. Add a callback function for when the countdown is "done" so that countdowns can be run in series.
2. Consume a series generator and use that to generate the next `count` value.
3. Have `makeCountdown` return an object that can be used to control the countdown.
4. Have fun!

Comment: this doesn't address the issue I have, I am actually trying to get 5 separate countdowns that happen one after another

Comment: @user975044 Updated with an example that uses closures to remember the "count" and "counter" variables per interval.

Comment: @user975044 This can get as fun/complex/generic as needed. jQuery has a queue implementation for dealing with animations - e.g. move left 20, then fade out